# How to calculate daily average frequency in a table in function of GROUP BY from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, average

I want to know which cinema room is more frequented daily and I need the values as relative frequency.

My tables are:

table1:

| client_id | cinema_room |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | C |
| 5 | A |
| 6 | C |
| 7 | B |
| 8 | A |
| 9 | B |
| 10 | B |
| 11 | B |
| 12 | A |
| 13 | C |
| 14 | A |
| 15 | A |
| 16 | B |

Table 2:

| day | client_id |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 1 |
| 01/01/2022 | 1 |
| 01/02/2022 | 1 |
| 01/02/2022 | 2 |
| 01/02/2022 | 4 |
| 01/03/2022 | 8 |
| 01/04/2022 | 14 |
| 01/04/2022 | 15 |
| 01/04/2022 | 16 |

So I need results like:

| day | cinema_room | avg_freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | A | 1 |
| 01/01/2022 | B | 0 |
| 01/01/2022 | C | 0 |
| 01/02/2022 | A | 0.33 |
| 01/02/2022 | B | 0.33 |
| 01/02/2022 | C | 0.33 |
| 01/03/2022 | A | 1 |
| 01/03/2022 | B | 0 |
| 01/03/2022 | C | 0 |
| 01/04/2022 | A | 0.66 |
| 01/04/2022 | B | 0.33 |
| 01/04/2022 | C | 0 |

What I've got by now is:

```
SELECT day , cinema_room, COUNT(t2.client_id) as t2_tot
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.client_id = t2.client_id
GROUP BY day, cinema_room
ORDER BY day
```

Its insufficient results are:

> NOTE 1: I'm counting, not even averaging.

> NOTE 2: The first three rows are wrong af.

| day | cinema_room | count_freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| None | A | 0 |
| None | B | 0 |
| None | C | 0 |
| 01/01/2022 | A | 3 |
| 01/01/2022 | B | 0 |
| 01/01/2022 | C | 0 |
| 01/02/2022 | A | 1 |
| 01/02/2022 | B | 1 |
| 01/02/2022 | C | 1 |
| 01/03/2022 | A | 1 |
| 01/03/2022 | B | 0 |
| 01/03/2022 | C | 0 |
| 01/04/2022 | A | 2 |
| 01/04/2022 | B | 1 |
| 01/04/2022 | C | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `CROSS JOIN` in a subquery which would be a calendar table, then aggregate `table1` & `table2` in another subquery the get count by each `cinema_room` per day.

```
SELECT t1.day , t1.cinema_room, SUM(IFNULL(t2.cnt,0)) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 tt2 WHERE t1.day = tt2.day) as t2_tot
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT day,cinema_room
 FROM table2 t2 CROSS JOIN table1
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT day,cinema_room,COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.client_id = t2.client_id
  GROUP BY day,cinema_room
) t2 ON t1.day = t2.day AND t1.cinema_room = t2.cinema_room
GROUP BY t1.day , t1.cinema_room
ORDER BY t1.day
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7d806e1d2230fe8dc629ec70c11c611d)

Comment: First of all: Many thanks!!! Second, I nedded to add *1.0 when dividing to get a REAL result when `SUM(IFNULL(t2.cnt,0)) *1.0 / ...`

Comment: One more thing (not less important), can you recommend me bibliography, link or something where to study to understand specifically what you did in depth. Before asking here I readed, look to documentations, stackoverflow questions and blogs and tried so hard coding wrong but nothing took away my uncertainty.